# How can i check if the user entered correct user name and password in DBA_USERS?

Tags: winforms, oracle19c

So i have a function for when clicking the button, the application would get the username and password stored in a table in oracle, and then compare it to the values entered in the textbox.
My question is that, instead of getting the values from the pre-created table, can i get the values from the DBA_USERS table, since the password is hashed?
Here's the code that fetch data from a created table:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string oradb = "Data Source=localhost:1522/ORCL;DBA Privilege=SYSDBA;User Id=sys;Password=123456;";

            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand();
            OracleParameter parm = new OracleParameter();
            OracleParameter parm1 = new OracleParameter();

            parm.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int64;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Users";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read()) {
                if (textBox1.Text.Equals(dr["username"].ToString()) && textBox2.Text.Equals(dr["password"].ToString()))
                    {
                    MessageBox.Show("Successful", "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    var menu = new Menu();
                    menu.Show();
                    this.Hide();                
                }
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: First of all, doing a `select * from users`  without condition is quite a bad idea. Imagine having many users in that table. Than you will have to compare them all in your own code. Instead I'd suggest doing something like `select count(*) from users where username = :username and password = :pwdhash`. This way you can just check if the query returns `1` or `0` to decide whether the login was successful or not

Comment: And also I'd suggest not to use the built in `DBA_USERS` table for your business logic

Comment: Then if normally, how can the apps access the hashed passwords for login?

Comment: *Normally* applications do not use database credentials in this manner. They would actually connect to the database as the user in question (thus letting the database do all the authentication internally) or they would maintain their own table of users and password hashes. Normal users (even back-end application users) should *not* have access to DBA_USERS, as it contains other information that should not be exposed to just anyone. Also, depending on your version of Oracle, the password hash may not be visible.